how to troubleshoot windows 10 connectivity issues for Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200
I've been struggling a lot with my WiFi connection because Windows decides to randomly disconnect every time.
The WiFi Device is an Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160Mhz.
I'm running Windows with very strict firewall rules and also a second firewall (Proxifier) that blocks the OS from bypassing the firewall.
Usually the first disconnects come right after the device boots up from sleep. Then it just works for a while until after some minutes or hours it decides to disconnect again. It also ignores the setting "automatically connect".
Here are some Windows event viewer logs:

1

2

3

How can I troubleshoot this?

Is the firewall responsible for this issue?

LSO triggered seems to be a known issue: https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/Netwtw10-6062-LSO-was-triggered/td-p/1578640


What are some ways to increase network stability?

Heyo,
Here are a few things you can try.
Limited Connectivity can mean a few things
Limited Connectivity can mean that you have a valid IP, but you can't get out of the network. It could also mean that you're not able to get a valid assignment from your router. Try resetting the route. Check Ipconfig /all command to see if you're getting a valid assignment. If you're not getting a valid assignment my hunch would be an issue with the router and we need more information.
Classic IT question and trial
Is your operating system up to date? Can you check with the intel update driver tool to see if you have a driver specific update? Some updates aren't found by windows but will be by the intel wireless driver support tool. Try rolling your network driver back to the previous version and see if it still stands.
The automatically reconnecting feature is part of wlansvc
Since wlansvc is the service in question per your event viewer it makes sense that it may not be automatically reconnecting. Check to make sure that the wlansvc is running to begin with. You can do this in the services.msc and see if the service says running. Make sure it's set to automatic, so it gets enabled on startup. You can use the "netsh.exe wlan show autoconfig" command to see what its setup as on different networks. You are checking this to ensure that for your network wlan autoconfig is enabled because that would stop it from reconnecting.
Disable your Proxifier
Does disabling your Proxifier work? If it does this could imply your Proxifier is blocking the wlansvc and you need to enable the ports it checks over. This could also be the case for your windows firewall but less likely.
I hope something in this list proved helpful even if it wasn't the answer but lead you to a new line of questioning!
